# Точное вхождение и место положения поисковой фразы в регулярных выражениях

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Помогите с регулярным выражением.
Суть, есть множество строчек из которых надо выбрать определенные, к примеру требуется найти все, что содержит строгое вхождение **detskie-tovary**

Строки которые должна найти регулярное выражение:

```
/detskie-tovary/igrushki/podvizhnye-igrushki-na-batareykah
detskie-tovary/igrushki/podvizhnye-igrushki-na-batareykah
detskie-tovary
https://myhost.com/detskie-tovary/igrushki/podvizhnye-igrushki-na-batareykah
```

В результат поиска по регулярному выражению не должны попасть следующие строки:

```
/detskie-tovary-malysh/igrushki/podvizhnye-igrushki-na-batareykah
detskie-tovary-malysh/igrushki/podvizhnye-igrushki-na-batareykah
detskie-tovary-malysh
/igrushki/detskie-tovary
https://myhost.com/detskie-tovary-malysh/igrushki/podvizhnye-igrushki-na-batareykah
```

Заранее спасибо за подсказку или в какую сторону посмотреть с регулярными выражениями.

Comment: А почему /igrushki/detskie-tovary не считается точным вхождением ?

Comment: @Mike нужно найти все вхождения начиная с первого символа urlPath за исключением первого прямого слеша. Надеюсь я понятно объяснил. :)

Comment: а Вам для Java PHP или ?

Comment: @НиколайГнап clickhouse, он поддерживает синтаксис re2

Comment: Что бы правильно составить регулярку, для начала выпишите точные условия: что может быть перед искомой строкой и что после нее. А потом все выражение сведеться буквально к `^(то что в начале1|то что в начале 2|...)detskie-tovary(/|$)`

Comment: @Mike Спасибо. Получилось. Не подумал о то, что в конце поставить прямой слеш или конец строки. https://regex101.com/r/NPUjU7/1

Answer (score 0):

[Сайт для проверки и составления  регулярных выражений](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output)

если верить сайту [detskie-tovary] так работает. Тестируйте на сайте

Comment: Спасибо посмотрю.